# toolbar turns to blank while scrolling the view

Tags: android, material-design

am using coordinator layout for hiding the toolbar but the problem is in some devices (android 4.4)am getting blank toolbar while scrolling the list ,please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/n_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_view_stub"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <!--add your layout content here -->


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <View
            style="@style/match_wrap"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/accent" />

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/content_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/fab_refine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"

        app:backgroundTint="@color/color_blue" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

     <ViewStub
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_view_stub"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

May it help!

Comment: It's happening only on few devices

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution I have to add an empty view just below the toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/n_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="@style/wrap_wrap"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/defaultLayoutPadding" />

            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_view_stub"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <!-- The empty is used for fixing the empty blank header issue,please don't remove it -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```